# adjusting UITableView's cell at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have subclassed a UITableViewCell. What I want to have is when I click on the cell, I added a UIView to the bottom of the cell and adjust the height of the cell accordingly. Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
MyCell* cell = (MyCell *) [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
UIView * options = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 27, cell.frame.size.width, 27)];
UIButton* button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[options addSubview:button1];
UIButton* button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[options addSubview:button2];
UIButton* button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[options addSubview:button3];
//did some layout calculation here to position the button
[cell addSubview:options];
}
```

Here's a [video](http://www.screenr.com/SPV) that illustrates the issue

Also I've tried to change the accessoryView of my cell from my custom UIButton to the regular UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosure but it didn't work

```
MyCell * cell = (MyCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:temp];
     [cell.accessoryView removeFromSuperview];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

If you're curious what I am trying to do, I am trying to create a tweetbot uitableviewcell, where you press the cell/row and it presents you with other options (retweets, etc) and also it was shown animated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView with dynamic cell heights -- what do I need to do to fix scrolling down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680067/uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-what-do-i-need-to-do-to-fix-scrolling-do) from the **Related** sidebar.

Comment: not sure why you declare this as duplicate... that question doesn't ask about adding a subview to a cell and resizing it

Comment: The body of that question seems to me to answer yours. However, I may be wrong, and that's why the auto-generated note says "possible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly understand what you are trying to do. But if you do want to animate the change of the UITableViewCell's height try to adjust it within [- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) and call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I think if you look at the video you'd understand. is the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate going to be called after I do the addSubview?

Comment: Actually I watched your video. No this delegate is not called by simply adding a subview. But it gets in fact called when you use those beginUpdates and endUpdates methods. (Look at my answer) Simply include them when adding your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Put controls into another cell and use

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

to show it and

```
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

to hide it.

Comment: I thought of this approach as well, however my UITable data source is from an NSArray of Message, this means that I would need to add something that is not a Message to the data source? Is this fine? I would also then need to modify the cellForRowAtIndexPath to handle this special case, correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. Whenever controls are not hidden your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: should return number_of_items + 1 and   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should return the appropriate cell  for controls.